# Does the Sargentini Report contain 37 factual errors?

Tags: politics, europe

On Tuesday, September 11, 2018, Viktor Orbán [stated](https://web.archive.org/web/20180912164841/https://visegradpost.com/en/2018/09/11/viktor-orban-denounces-the-blackmail-of-the-eu-full-speech/) that [the Sargentini report](https://web.archive.org/web/20180421103258/http://www.europarl.europa.eu/resources/library/media/20180411RES01553/20180411RES01553.pdf)

> includes thirty-seven major factual errors

Does it?

Comment: I am not sure how this can be answered: (1) there is no list of mistakes to verify and (2) no clear definition of what Orban _meant_ so we can derive it univocally.